# Can't boot into Windows 10 from GRUB menu, even though the option of Windows 10 is there?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-10

I recently dual booted my Lenovo windows 10 laptop, windows 10 + Ubuntu 18.04. Installing Linux in itself was a hassle, but now it is done.

However, now when I power on my laptop, I reach the grub screen as shown in images:

[image: GRUB menu]

[image: GRUB menu]

Here, I do have an option of Windows 10. But when I move over to it, and click it, the screen color changes to black or something and then again this GRUB menu screen reappears.

So while I can choose to boot into Ubuntu from here (first option), I am not able to boot into my Windows 10.

Pressing <kbd>e</kbd> on GRUB menu, when Ubuntu is selected, the following options are seen:

[image: GRUB editor]

Pressing <kbd>e</kbd> on GRUB menu, when Windows 10 is selected, the following options are seen:

[image: GRUB editor]

After using boot-repair on Ubuntu, the issue still persists, but in the GRUB menu another entry for booting to Windows has now been created, but using both the options, the problem still is the very same!

[Here is the boot-repair URL](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6BvJDwJjzQ/)

Could someone please look into it, and help out?

#### Background info

While installing Ubuntu using live USB, I could only boot into Windows 10 directly, wasn't getting a GRUB menu to choose Ubuntu/Windows.

So in Windows, I installed EasyBCD and created a new entry for `GRUB (legacy)`, which didn't work either in giving me a GRUB menu/choice to boot into Windows/Ubuntu.

So I created another entry, now for `grub2`, which finally worked, so when I restarted, I did get the GRUB menu screen and could boot into ubuntu on startup.

But then I noticed that now I can't boot into Windows even though the option for that is coming on the GRUB menu.

Also I am new to Linux, feeling kind of helpless.

Comment: When you edit the grub menu entries, by pressing e at boot. What do the options look like.

Comment: Haven't tried that yet. Do u recommend me, doing it? @michael prokopec

Comment: Yea, people need to see what the option points to in order to help you properly.

Comment: Is Windows UEFI or BIOS? But you probably need to turn off Windows fast start up. If UEFI you can directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu. But if BIOS, you have to temporarily reinstall a Windows or Windows type boot loader to MBR to boot Windows, repair Windows & then restore grub. May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the summary report ( not full report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @michael prokopec, please have a look at the updated question. The last lines contain links to images of the options

Comment: Since it is saying MSDOS for partitions, that is a BIOS boot. You need to use your Windows repair disk to restore Windows boot loader and fix Windows. You may be able to use Boot-Repair to put a Windows type boot loader into MBR, but it cannot do Windows fixes.

Comment: @oldfred  I had turned off fast startup when only windows could be booted (directly) so that I could later get an option on startup to boot into ubuntu or windows as per choice. And yes it is BIOS. Since I can access my Ubuntu right now, you suggest me to install the boot-repair from terminal on Ubuntu and run it to fix the windows boot issue, right?

Comment: @oldfred I don't have a windows repair disc, so how do u suggest I go about resolving the issue? Also, According to you, this issue is because the windows bootloader is not working?

Comment: You should see in your grub file before each boot option description `menuentry`, not `setparams`. I've not seen that before in a grub file. If you go into your BIOS is it set up as 'Legacy' or as 'UEFI'?

Comment: @oldfred As you suggested, I tried using boot repair, and have updated the main question text, could you please look into the report? Link: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/6BvJDwJjzQ/

Comment: I agree with oldfred. It looks as though the MBR of the drive is amiss. Also, check your UEFI and Legacy settings in BIOS. Most operating systems support UEFI so there is really no reason to use Legacy. However whatever setting was active during install is the way it must stay. As stated here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23161_01/html/E37044/gnchj.html

Comment: Windows with updates will turn fast start up back on. So since you have the old BIOS/MBR configuration whenever Windows does that or needs other repairs, you will need your Windows repair disk and go thru changing BIOS boot temporarily to Windows & then back to grub. Grub only boots working Windows. Once you can boot Windows make a Windows repair flash drive, as you will need it. With UEFI you can always directly boot Windows from UEFI boot menu when it has issues.